# Replace values in a pandas dataframe with a dict

Tags: python, pandas

I'll have a pandas dataframe and looking for a method to replace the values for `column = c` with the mean value for `column = a` and `column = b`.

Being a novice at Python, I have checked the replace function, and the possibility to create a dict to perform the replacement. My failed attempt is visible below.

If anyone has any suggestions I would be thrilled.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': ['a', ' b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ], 'value': range(0,9)})

dict = {"(df[df['column'] == 'c']['value'].values)": "df[df['column'] == 'a']['value'].mean()"}

df.replace(dict)
```

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set and select column `value` by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['column'] == 'c', 'value'] = df.loc[df['column'] == 'a', 'value'].mean()
print (df)
  column     value
0      a  0.000000
1      b  1.000000
2      a  2.000000
3      b  3.000000
4      b  4.000000
5      a  5.000000
6      b  6.000000
7      c  2.333333
8      d  8.000000
```

Or if need test multiple values use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df.loc[df['column'] == 'c', 'value'] = df.loc[df['column'].isin(['a','b']), 'value'].mean()
print (df)
  column     value
0      a  0.000000
1      b  1.000000
2      a  2.000000
3      b  3.000000
4      b  4.000000
5      a  5.000000
6      b  6.000000
7      c  3.333333
8      d  8.000000
```

Comment: OK! That's nice! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I should replace 12 values (one for every month of 2020) with the mean values of the same month 2019, 2018 and 2017. Would it be a good idea to use your your second solution and insert it into a for loop? Maybe a zip for loop?

Comment: there are datetimes? How working `df.groupby(df['dates'].dt.year)['value'].transform('mean')`  if understand well what need ?

Comment: @Henrik - It replace means by each years, but maybe need something else.

Comment: Well, yes, sorry. Actually is match/april 2020 to jan 2021 (Corona)...